# Social learning and diffusion

Tags: information, networks

I'm looking at the literature on information dissemination within networks and came across the concept of diffusion of information in [Alatas et al.,2016](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w18351/w18351.pdf). The way I understood is diffusion refers to the spread of information. In another paper on networks [Jackson,2011](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.216.1849&rep=rep1&type=pdf), i came across the concept of learning. According to Jackson,2011, learning is distinct from diffusion (pg 44-46) in the sense that "The most obvious difference is that individuals no longer fall into simple
categories such as “infected” or not, but instead might have beliefs or opinions that vary
more continuously and are influenced in more complicated ways by interaction with their neighbors".

**Q.1: Despite reading this quoted statement, I'm not at all sure of how learning differs from diffusion, and would appreciate if someone could explain learning and the difference between these two concepts with the help of some simple example.**

moreover, Alatas et al state in the abstract "We develop a model of semi-Bayesian learning on networks,... show that networks the model predicts to be more diffusive differentially benefit from community targeting."

**Q.2. So are Alatas et al talking about learning or diffusion. It seems to me they are using a model of learning to study diffusion, which does not make sense, so I'm definitely reading it wrong**

Now, [Mobius and Rosenblat,2006](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-economics-120213-012609?casa_token=PC37hn0wm4sAAAAA:OXybTbHEMz57WaZKsYrSl7KnlmtWsffAdUtWLUAK49oaT5kisveo2wBG3Ahq3m6H-GuP1Vkr5l1Kyiu0) in Social Learning in Economics, talk about contagion studies (pg. 9) and says: " People learn from neighbors about the existence of certain products,rather than receiving signals that help them update their beliefs about the quality of the product.These situations are more appropriately captured by diffusion models than by standard social learning models".

**Q.3: so, according to this paper, does diffusion fall under the umbrella of social learning?**

I apologize for the possible confusion in the question but this is because I'm very much confused about the two concepts and what exactly the first paper is exploring.

I would appreciate any leads. Thanks